# How to pass the second parameter to Mongo::Collection#find?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

This is a newbie question. I find the method definition in the YARD Rdoc:

```
(Object) find(selector = {}, opts = {})


Options Hash (opts):
:fields (Array, Hash)
```

then I try this coll.find('English' => 'fulcrum',{English:1,Chinese:1}), want the result 'English' field is fulcrum ,and only return English and Chinese field, but Ruby punished me with the this

```
irb(main):018:0> coll.find('English' => 'fulcrum',{English:1,Chinese:1})
SyntaxError: (irb):18: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting tASSOC
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):019:0>
```

I want to know why, thanks

after correct the syntax problem by the suggestion by @mu, I got Unknown options error:

```
irb(main):013:0> coll.find({English:'fulcrum'},{English:1, :Chinese => 1})RuntimeError: Unknown options [{:English=>1, :Chinese=>1}]
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.5.2/lib/mongo/collection.rb:234:in `find'
    from (irb):13
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):014:0>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Ruby sees an unwrapped Hash in argument list:

```
o.m(k => v, ...)
```

it assumes that you really mean this:

```
o.m({ k => v, ... })
```

So, when you say this:

```
coll.find('English' => 'fulcrum', {English: 1, Chinese: 1})
```

Ruby sees this:

```
coll.find({ 'English' => 'fulcrum', {English: 1, Chinese: 1} })
```

A Hash is a perfectly valid key so Ruby expects it to be followed by a `=> value`:

```
coll.find('English' => 'fulcrum', {English: 1, Chinese: 1} => some_value)
```

and that's where the error message comes from:

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting tASSOC
```

If you want to pass two hashes, you need to wrap the first one in braces:

```
coll.find({'English' => 'fulcrum'}, {English: 1, Chinese: 1})
```

---

The second argument to [`find`](
http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#find-instance_method) should be an options Hash and it looks like you want the `:fields` option and you can give that an array of names instead of a noisy Hash:

```
coll.find({'English' => 'fulcrum'}, :fields => %w[English Chinese])
```

Comment: @yozloy: I assumed the interface was like the MongoDB shell, I've added an update that should fix the new error.